# Flow Builder - What is the maximum number of conditions in a decision element?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, flow-builder

Could not find anything mentioned in [flow limits and considerations article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations.htm&type=5) but I may have missed something.

Is there any documentation mentioning the maximum number of conditions that can be added in a single decision element ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no per-decision-element limits, but keep in mind that each condition may have to be tested, which will count against CPU time, so more conditions means a higher likelihood of reaching that limit.